# Getting CORS error in Http request using ionic4

Tags: ionic4

Getting error in API calling

> ERROR => Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:3003/graphql' from origin 'http://localhost:8101' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

```
apollo: Apollo,
    httpLink: HttpLink
  ) {
    apollo.create({
      link: httpLink.create({ uri: 'localhost:3003/graphql}),
      cache: new InMemoryCache()
    });
```

CORS-enabled for all origins (Node Api)

Answer (score 2):

As error refers `only supported for protocol schemes: http....` which certainly means you've just forgotten to put the `https` or `http` on the request in your code

So please note `localhost:3003/graphql` must change to either `http://localhost:3003/graphql` or `https://localhost:3003/graphql`

```
apollo: Apollo,
    httpLink: HttpLink
  ) {
    apollo.create({
      link: httpLink.create({ uri: 'http://localhost:3003/graphql'}),
      cache: new InMemoryCache()
    });
```